# Criteria query to select multiple columns in hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

How can i select multiple columns from a table using criteria query.

```
Select testid,marks from user where id='uid' and name='uname';
```

I am able to get only testid but along with testid I need marks also Can anyone modify the below query to get both testid and marks.

```
Session ses = sessionFactory.getCurentSession();
Criteria c = ses.createCriteria(user.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", uid));
c.add(Restrictions.eq("name", uname));
c.setProjection(Pojections.distinct(Projections.property("testid")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to give a `ProjectionList` to your `Projections.distinct`:

```
Session ses = sessionFactory.getCurentSession();
Criteria c = ses.createCriteria(user.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", uid));
c.add(Restrictions.eq("name", uname));

ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
pl.add(Projections.property("testid"));
pl.add(Projections.property("marks"));

c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(pl));
```